# amp stories facebook share error

Tags: amp-html, google-amp, amp-stories

> Error:  Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID

**I added following**

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
```

**CDN linked**

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-social-share-0.1.js
https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-facebook-0.1.js
```

Comment: you need a value for `fb:page_id` Technically it should be in `bookend` like this `{"share-providers": {"facebook": {"app_id": ""}} ...}`

Comment: now fb share option working , but its not fetching og title, description , image url  ? do you any idea about that

Comment: hard to offer advice about a non-visible document.

Comment: Can you provide the full source code to your story (a link?) and more information about where you're seeing this error?